# Error with Google Maps autocomplete and Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, autocomplete

I'm trying to use Google Maps autocomplete with Angular 6.
I have an input text inside a modal.
Here's the code:

```
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" google-place (onSelect)="autoMaps()" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on" runat="server" />

autocompleteFn() {

        const input = window.HTMLInputElement(document.getElementById('searchTextField'));
        const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        console.log(el);
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {           
            const placee = autocomplete.getPlace();
            console.log(placee.name);
            console.log(placee.geometry.location.lat());
            console.log(placee.geometry.location.lng());
            let address = '';
              if (placee.address_components) {
                address = [
                  (placee.address_components[0] && placee.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                  (placee.address_components[1] && placee.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                  (placee.address_components[2] && placee.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                ].join(' ');
              }
              console.log(address);
        });
      }
```

When running it and opening the modal, I get this error:

> InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement

Answer (score 0):

Your input element (#searchTextField) is itself an

> HTMLInputElement

Maybe you rewrite the begining of **autocompleteFn()** like so:

```
const input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
console.log(input);
const autocomplete = 
    new  google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input as HTMLInputElement);
...
```

A more Angular way of getting a ref to the text input element is to use the

> @ViewChild

decorator to query the view. That would look something like following inside your View-Class:

```
@ViewChild('searchTextField') input : ElementRef;
```

And corresponding in your template file:

```
<input #searchTextField ...
```

Thate way you could use the declared variable **input** like following in your function:

```
...
const autocomplete = 
new  google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input as HTMLInputElement);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `window.HTMLInputElement(document.getElementById('searchTextField'))` to `document.getElementById('searchTextField') as HTMLInputElement`

**Html**

```
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" google-place (onSelect)="autoMaps()" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on" runat="server" />
```

**ts**

```
  autocompleteFn() {

    const input = document.getElementById('searchTextField') as HTMLInputElement;
    const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    console.log(el);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        const placee = autocomplete.getPlace();
        console.log(placee.name);
        console.log(placee.geometry.location.lat());
        console.log(placee.geometry.location.lng());
        let address = '';
          if (placee.address_components) {
            address = [
              (placee.address_components[0] && placee.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
              (placee.address_components[1] && placee.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
              (placee.address_components[2] && placee.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
          }
          console.log(address);
    });
  }
```